# Четыре звания или четыре званий?

Tags: орфография, склонение, числительные, существительные, количественно-именное-сочетание

Недавно задалась вопросом, как правильно: четыре звания или четыре званий? Три звания или три званий? Два звания или два званий?

Answer (score 0):

**Звание** - существительное среднего рода единственного числа.
Соответственно, падежная форма с числительными "три" и "четыре" будет иметь вид **"три звания"**, **"четыре звания"** (аналогично - ***"три предложения"***, ***"четыре столетия"*** и т.д.)